# Heroku puppeteer chrome browser launch issue

Tags: windows, heroku, next.js, puppeteer

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/app/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-122.0.6261.57/chrome-linux64/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I've looked at older posts regarding this issue but nothing seems to work.  Tried installing the buildpack, relocated the cache, no sandbox etc.  I'm not using Linux.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless:false,
    'args' : [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ]
  })
```

Comment: "I'm not using Linux"—but Heroku is

Comment: "Tried installing the buildpack"—which buildpacks, specifically? You generally need two of them: one for the browser, and another for the driver.

Comment: This is the one I was coming across to install.  heroku buildpacks:set jontewks/puppeteer

Comment: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer.tgz

Comment: Have you included an appropriate `heroku-postbuild` script as documented in that buildpack's README?

Comment: Yes I tried.  Anytime I try to do any .cache changes I get application error after deploy. When I get the site up but doesn't function.... Logs..."Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 122.0.6261.69). This can occur if either 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /app/.cache/puppeteer) For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration."  Tried the guide directions didn't work.